# htaccess removing folder from url externally and redirecting internally

Tags: .htaccess

I manged to remove the folder from the url but I cannot redirect back to it. Please help!

```
# externally redirect /dir/foo to /foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} pages/
RewriteRule pages/(.*)$ $1 [L,NC,R]

# internally forward /foo to /dir/foo
#what goes here?
```

EDIT:
Also, how can I put this on the same code?

```
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile.php?username=$1 [L]
```

I want the user name to be like this localhost/test/user1 rather than localhost/test/profile.php?username=user1

Answer (score 0):

Internal redirect mean URL rewriting (if I'm not misunderstood)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dir/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dir/$1 [L]
```

Note: To prevent external redirect I didn't used `[R]` flag.

**EDIT**

I can see you hostead on `localhost` in subdirectory `/test` So, you'l have to set `RewriteBase` as following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dir/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test/dir/$1 [L]
```

**EDIT** Included user profile rewrite rule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test/profile.php?username=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dir/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test/dir/$1 [L]
```

Comment: this crushes my whole website.. I want localhost/test/pages/info to go to localhost/test/info

Comment: this doesn't seem to work. it crushes everything too